# Difficulty Accessing Members of Tuple in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a variable titled F.

Describe F returns:
`F: {group: bytearray,indexkey: {(indexkey: chararray)}}`

Dump F returns:

```
(321,{(CHOW),(DREW)})
(5011,{(CHOW),(DREW)})
(5825,{(TANNER),(SPITZENBERGER)})
(16631,{(CHOW),(DREW)})
(34299,{(CHOW),(DREW)})
(35044,{(TANNER),(SPITZENBERGER)})
(65623,{(CHOW),(DREW)})
(74597,{(SPITZENBERGER),(TANNER)})
(83499,{(SPITZENBERGER),(TANNER)})
(90257,{(SPITZENBERGER),(TANNER)})
```

What I need is to produce an output that looks like this (only 1st row as an example):

`(321,DREW,{(CHOW)})`

I've tried using deference to pull out the first element by using this:

```
G = FOREACH F generate indexkey.$0;
```

But, this still returns the whole tuple.

Can anyone suggest a method for doing this? I was under the impression that the deference operator should allow me to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can't index into bags like that. The reason for that is bags don't have any notion of ordering. Selecting the first item in a bag should be treated as picking a random one.

Either way, if you want only one item instead of all of them you can used a nested FOREACH to pull a LIMIT of 1:

```
first = FOREACH F {
        lim = LIMIT indexkey 1;
        GENERATE group, lim;
}
```

(disclaimer: I can't test this code right now, if it doesn't work let me know. Hopefully you can get the gist)

You can take this a bit further and FLATTEN it to remove the bag of one item entirely, but be careful in that if the bag is empty i think you throw away the entire record in this case.

```
first = FOREACH F {
        lim = LIMIT indexkey 1;
        GENERATE group, FLATTEN(lim);
}
```